# Choose randomly a number from two columns rstudio

Tags: r, random, sample

I have this data frame and I' trying to create a new column considering the data in the first column and the column called "zero", I've been using sample(), for an interval from (0,df$first) but It gaves me a number between 0 and the data in the first column, not one(0) or another (as an example 9).

Initial data frame:

```
> df
  first zero 
1     9    0   
2     8    0   
3    16    0
```

What I want is something like this:

```
> df
  first zero new
1     9    0   9
2     8    0   0
3    16    0  16
```

I really appreciate your answers or opinions. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you want this

```
set.seed(1)
df$new <- df[cbind(seq(nrow(df)),
                   sample(2,nrow(df),replace = TRUE))]
```

such that

```
> df
  first zero new
1     9    0   9
2     8    0   0
3    16    0  16
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(first = c(9, 8, 16), zero = c(0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: @SalmaGuzmán what do you mean? For each row, `new` is either from `first` or `zero`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, the code works just perfect! I'm really thankful! Do I have to change something if first and zero are not the only two variables?

Comment: @SalmaGuzmán Yo can remove the line `set.seed(1)`. Also, if you have more than two columns, you can replace `sample(2,nrow(df),replace = TRUE)` by `sample(ncol(df),nrow(df),replace = TRUE)` for general cases

Comment: but how do yo specify in that code line that you should select column first and zero if you have more numerical columns ?

Comment: @SalmaGuzmán `sample(ncol(df),nrow(df),replace = TRUE)` generates random integers from `1` to `ncol(df)`, which corresponding to the column number

Comment: For the data frame in the question everything is just perfect, but I'm running the code for a bigger data frame and it is not considering column first and zero, it gives me random numbers, I'm not really sure if I'm doing something wrong or if I have to specify mote things in the sample line

Comment: This is what I'm running:
df$new<-sample(c(df$first, df$zero),nrow(df),replace = TRUE)
The bigger data frame has 30 columns and some of them are numerical, also first column has NA's

Comment: @SalmaGuzmán maybe you can try `na.omit(c(df$first, df$zero))`, but sorry that I did not get your point for the problem

Comment: You got it right! I was not understanding, finally I got it, I just specified the columns 4 and 49 (first and zero) in my bigger data frame!